# Integration of JIRA and Subversion Workflow

Tags: svn, workflow, jira

I'm wondering if there's an easy or preferred method to achieve the following workflow using JIRA and Subversion:

I'm not sure which approach is better, but I would be fine with either one:

```
a) Developer Commits BUG-321 to SVN with bug # in commit comment, 
   which automatically transitions the issue's workflow state to "resolved"

   **OR**

b) In JIRA, the developer attempts to transition BUG-321 to "resolved", 
   which triggers an event that forces the developer to commit code first 
   before the transition can happen
```

**NOTE -- The main goal is to get the build number back from subversion and put it into a field of the bug once it's marked as resolved, so I can automatically let our QA people know which build number a bug was fixed in.**

Is this something I can easily achieve?

Answer (score 0):

a) can be done rather easy with *-commit hook, which interact with Jira, using it's API

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use [FishEye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/) and have the [JIRA FishEye Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jirafisheyeplugin) installed, you can:

- [block transitions if not code has been committed against a ticket](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/FISH/JIRA+FishEye+Plugin;jsessionid=596EAC10810D028DDFC660D010C4B719#JIRAFishEyePlugin-EnhanceyourJIRAworkflowwithcode%5Candreviewbasedconditions)
- [setup commit commands to auto-transition tickets on commits](https://blogs.atlassian.com/2009/10/dragon_slayer_supplement_action_issues_with_commit_commands/)